# To create event handlers (subscribers) in Azure Event Grid Using Java

Tags: java, spring, azure

I am exploring to use Azure Event Grid in our microservices applications based on Spring Boot. I was able to use the demo application available on Microsoft site. However, it uses Azure Event Hub as a handler (subscriber) which I want to avoid. My questions are:

1. What's the best way to publish and subscribe to events in Spring Boot applications running in Azure? I can think of (1) use the REST API (but some of the documentation links didn't work) (2) use the Azure Java SDK
2. The articles I saw used either Azure function or Webhook or EventHub as handlers. In my case, one or more Spring Boot Microservice would-be subscribers.

I would appreciate a sample code using Java to implement Event Grid Handler.

Comment: Do we have any solution for above mentioned scenario?

Comment: Did we find any solution for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic), to publish to an event grid custom topic you can send

POST https://.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events?api-version=2018-01-01

Headers:

- aeg-sas-key: the custom topic key. You can retrieve it from azure portal

Body:

```
[{
  "id": "1807",
  "eventType": "recordInserted",
  "subject": "myapp/vehicles/motorcycles",
  "eventTime": "2017-08-10T21:03:07+00:00",
  "data": {
    "make": "Ducati",
    "model": "Monster"
  },
  "dataVersion": "1.0"
}]
```